# React-Native (redux) error: Could not find "store" in context of "Connect(App)"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I'm getting this weird error in my react-native app. Where I'm using redux to save the user when its is fetched from the firebase database.
Here is the error:

[image: Error I'm getting]

and here is my code in App.js:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ToastAndroid } from 'react-native';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import RNBootSplash from "react-native-bootsplash";
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

// Navigation
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import BottomTabNavigator from './src/navigation/BottomTabNavigation';
import AuthenticationStack from './src/navigation/AuthenticationStack';

// redux imports
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { saveUserPrefs, saveUser } from './src/redux';
import {store} from './src/redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


const App = (props) => {

  const { saveUserPrefs, saveUser } = props;


  let isLoggedIn = false;


  useEffect(() => {
 
    auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      // if not already login go back to login screen
      if(!user){
          isLoggedIn = false;
      } else {
          isLoggedIn = true
          RNBootSplash.hide({ fade: true }); // hide the splash screen
          ToastAndroid.show("Logged In", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
          // save the user & userPrefs in store (redux)
          saveUser(user);
          saveUserPrefs(user.uid);
      }
  });
  }, [])
    
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {isLoggedIn ? <BottomTabNavigator /> : <AuthenticationStack />}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  userReducer: state.userReducer
})


export default connect(mapStateToProps, { saveUserPrefs , saveUser})(App);
```

and here is my redux code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { combineReducers, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

// Actions
export const saveUserPrefs = (userId) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {

        try { 
            console.log('in userlogin function');  
            const data = await firestore().collection('Users').doc(userId).collection('userPrefs').get();
            dispatch({ type: 'SAVE_USER_PREFS', payload: data.docs[0]._data });
        } catch (err) {
            dispatch({ type: 'ON_ERROR', payload: err });
        }

    }
}

export const saveUser = (user) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {

        try {
            dispatch({ type: 'SAVE_USER', payload: user})
        } catch (err) {
            dispatch({ type: 'ON_ERROR', payload: err });
        }

    }
}

// reducers

const userReducer = (state = {}, action) => {

    switch(action.type){
        case 'SAVE_USER_PREFS':
            return {
                ...state,
                userPrefs: action.payload
            }
        case 'SAVE_USER':
            return {
                ...state,
                user: action.payload
            }
        case 'ON_ERROR':
            return {
                ...state,
                appError: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }

}

// root reducer
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    userReducer,
})


// store
export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

I'm new to redux but I read that I have to put the connect method in the component I'm using to get the actions in order to save in the store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the `App component` you cannot `connect` to the redux
just wrap your App within another component, that have the `Provider`

Example code

```
const AppWrapper = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

And remember to delete `<Provider store={store}>` in your `App component`